# Change height of svg icon fa-edit on angular project

Tags: html, css, angular

What i need to is to edit the height of the icon to 1.5em instead of 1em. But i can't seem to find .svg-inline--fa. I don't have any CSS files for the icons cause i used npm install.

**Commands that i run to download the svg icons on angular**

```
npm install @fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core
npm install @fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons
npm install @fortawesome/angular-fontawesome
```

Fortawesome: https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome

[image]

```
<fa-icon [icon]="faEdit" size="lg" (click)="open(content)">Edit</fa-icon>
```

**When i inspect element, this is the CSS of the icon**

```
.svg-inline--fa {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: inherit;
    height: 1em;
    overflow: visible;
    vertical-align: -0.125em
}
```

Also imported `import { faEdit } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';`
to my component ts

Update: Use e.g. transform="down-5" to move the icon down.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can just edit the size of you icon with `transform` in you html component.

Like this:

```html
<fa-icon [icon]="['fas', 'coffee']" transform="shrink-9 right-4"></fa-icon>
```

Check [fontawesome advanced usage](https://github.com/FortAwesome/angular-fontawesome/blob/master/docs/usage/features.md#advanced-usage)

Answer (score 10):

Anyone searching the same thing:

In that documentation (mentioned by Shifenis) you can use size attribute

```
 <fa-icon [icon]="['fas', 'coffee']" size="6x"></fa-icon>
```

Simpler and more readable

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me.

https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/styling/sizing-icons

```
<fa-icon [icon]="faYoutube" class="fa-2x"></fa-icon>
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be a bit hackey, but I was able to fine-tune the icon size by changing the font size.  This works because the icon size is proportional to the font size.

```
    <fa-icon [icon]="faYoutube" style="font-size:1.5em"></fa-icon>
```